# 3-D batch matrix multiplication without knowing batch size

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, matrix-multiplication

I'm currently writing a tensorflow program that requires multiplying a batch of 2-D tensors (a 3-D tensor of shape `[None,...]`) with a 2-D matrix `W`. This requires turning `W` into a 3-D matrix, which requires knowing the batch size.

I have not been able to do this; `tf.batch_matmul` is no longer usable, `x.get_shape().as_list()[0]` returns `None`, which is invalid for a reshaping/tiling operation. Any suggestions? I've seen some people use `config.cfg.batch_size`, but I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to use a combination of [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) (which returns the shape *at runtime*) and [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) (which accepts the *dynamic* shape).

```py
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 2, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.ones([3, 4]), dtype=tf.float32)
print(x.shape)                # Dynamic shape: (?, 2, 3)

batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]   # A tensor that gets the batch size at runtime
W_expand = tf.expand_dims(W, axis=0)
W_tile = tf.tile(W_expand, multiples=[batch_size, 1, 1])
result = tf.matmul(x, W_tile) # Can multiply now!

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  feed_dict = {x: np.ones([10, 2, 3])}
  print(sess.run(batch_size, feed_dict=feed_dict))    # 10
  print(sess.run(result, feed_dict=feed_dict).shape)  # (10, 2, 4)
```