# TensorFlow - Cannot get the shape of matrix with the get_shape command

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, tensorflow, shapes

I can't seem to get the shape of the tensor when I do

```
get_shape().as_list()
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
matrix1 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32) 
matrix2 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    a = sess.run(matrix1, {matrix1: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]})
    b = sess.run(matrix2, {matrix2: [[10,11,12],[13,14,15], [16,17,18]]})
    print(a.get_shape().as_list()) #ERROR
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

I want to know the shape of the matrix so that I can take in an arbitrary matrix and loop through its rows and columns.

Comment: Not an expert, but if it is a numpy.ndarray, isnt the method called [.shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)?

Comment: `a` is a numpy.ndarray, so you should use `a.shape`

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Just summarizing the discussion in the comments with few notes</sup>

Both `matrix1` and `a` are multidimensional arrays, but there is a difference:

- `matrix1` is an instance of [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), which supports two ways to access the shape: `matrix1.shape` attribute and `matrix1.get_shape()` method.
- The result of `tf.Tensor` evaluation, `a`, is a numpy [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), which has just `a.shape` attribute.

Historically, `tf.Tensor` had only `get_shape()` method, `shape` was added later to make it similar to numpy. And one more note: in tensorflow, tensor shape can be dynamic (like in your example), in which case neither `get_shape()` nor `shape` will return a number. In this case, one can use [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) function to access it in runtime (here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48180946/712995) when it might be useful).