# How to print the value of shape of the tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, tensor

I was used the function

```
print tf.shape(image)
```

The output likes

```
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0)
```

I want to know what is the value inside the shape (like the dimensions). How can I access it to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) returns a tensor that contains the shape of an argument. This is useful when one of the dimensions is *dynamic*, i.e., is `None` statically.

You can use `image.shape` (or `image.get_shape()`) to get the static shape, or can also evaluate `tf.shape(image)` in a session.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48268674/712995).