# Batch Matrix Multiplication with Dynamic Batch Size

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, transformation-matrix

I am writing a procedure using Batch Matrix Multiplication, maybe not in under a common setting. I am considering the following inputs:

```
# Let's say I have a list of points in R^3, from 3 distinct objects
# (so my data batch has 3 data entry)
# X: (B1+B2+B3) * 3 
X = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],
                  [2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2],
                  [3,3,3],])
# To indicate which object the points are corresponding to,
# I have a list of indices (say, starting from 0):
# idx: (B1+B2+B3)
idx = torch.tensor([0,0,1,1,1,2])
# For each point from the same object, I want to multiply it to a 3x3 matrix, A_i.
# As I have 3 objects here, I have A_0, A_1, A_2.
# A: 3 x 3 x 3
A = torch.tensor([[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],
                  [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]],
                  [[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]])
```

And the desired output is:

```
out = X.unsqueeze(1).bmm(A[idx])
out = out.squeeze(1)                # just to remove excessive dimension
# out = torch.tensor([[[1,1,1]],[[1,1,1]],            # obj0 mult with A_0
                      [[2,2,2]],[[2,2,2]],[[2,2,2]],  # obj1 mult with A_1
                      [[3,3,3]],])                    # obj2 mult with A_2
```

It is actually pretty handy in pytorch, just one line!

Here, I want to improve this procedure. Note that I am using *A[idx]* to replicate one matrix A_i for each point, so I can use torch.bmm() function here (1 point <-> 1 matrix). Afaik, it will need to allocate memory for intermediate representation of *A[idx]*. In general, if I have BN objects in my data batch, size of A[idx] = (B1+...+BN)*3*3, which can be very large.

Therefore, I am wondering if replication of matrix A_i can be avoided.

I have found most previously asked questions about Batch Mat. Mult. only assume fixed batch size. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180946/3-d-batch-matrix-multiplication-without-knowing-batch-size) the same question as mine was asked, and a solution in tensorflow was provided. However, the solution was implemented using tf.tile(), which is also replicating matrices.

---

To summarize, my question is about batch matrix multiplication, while achieving:

```
- dynamic batch size
    - input shape: (B1+...+BN) x 3
    - index shape: (B1+...+BN)
- memory efficiency
    - probably w/out massive replication of matrix
```

I am using pytorch here, but I also accept other implementations. I also accept representing inputs (e.g. matrices to multiply, A) in other structures if it results in a better memory efficiency.